# is it possible to use MapView to show bike shops within a certain radius of my current location?

Tags: react-native, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, react-native-maps

I am using MapView with React Native and want to populate all bike shops near by my current location. I have the MapView displaying my current location:

```
<MapView
      style={styles.map}
      mapType="standard"
      zoomEnabled={true}
      pitchEnabled={true}
      showsUserLocation={true}
      followsUserLocation={true}
      showsCompass={true}></MapView>
```

I know I can use Markers to set pins on the map, and I know I can use Google Places API to search for Near By Places or Text strings but I am not sure how to combine the two or if there is an easier way to populate the bike shops. I can't have a library of every single bike shop in the world, that would obviously be ridiculous.

Am I going about building out the map correctly? If I do use markers, is there a way to query for "bike shops" within a 10 mile radius of my current location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a great resource and answered my question. I won't mark this as correct to see if there are any other suggestions of better ways to go about this.

https://handyopinion.com/fetch-nearest-places-in-react-native-using-google-places-api/